# how to get the current date by difference time to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want data between yesterday 7Am to today 7Am, for that i am trying to get today 7AM(2018-11-22 07:00:00 Am) for that i am trying this.

```
select getdate() as todate,dateadd(hh,-7,getdate()) as sehrsrem,
       datediff(hour,dateadd(hh,-7,getdate()),getdate()) 
from   dump;
```

By using datediff() i am getting number 7 ,how to get full date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this will gives you the required date time

```
select  dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1) + '07:00' as yesterday_7am,
        dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),  0) + '07:00' as today_7am
```

to get data between these date use it at `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE  date_column >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1) + '07:00'
AND    date_col    <  dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),  0) + '07:00'
```

Comment: If it wasn't for your answer I wouldn't understand the question.
It's easier to cast  GETDATE() to DATE type. That will remove the time part of the datetime.
See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By converting GETDATE() to DATE type we remove the time part. After that all you have to is add 7 hours to get today's desired value and subtract 17 hours to receive yesterdays desired time.

```
DECLARE @ToDay DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

SELECT DATEADD(HH,   7, @ToDay) AS Today
     , DATEADD(HH, -17, @ToDay) AS Yesterday
```

[image]